# How to draw lines with WinApi on desktop C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics, gdi

I want to draw lines on the desktop without using a window. I tried this code:

```
const HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);

while (true) {
    MoveToEx(dc, 100, 100, NULL);
    LineTo(dc, 50, 50);
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I realize this?

Comment: "*without using a window*" - why?

Comment: Also, your code works. You probably draw with a color (black, right in the black console window, I guess) that isn't clearly visible or the line is too short.to notice. `LineTo(dc, 1920, 1080);` (or whatever your screen resolution is) may make it noticeable.

Comment: Not sure what you expects and/or what you're ultimately after. It does display a black line but that black line can be erased by mostly anything since you don't own the desktop. If you move a composited window (for example, Windows 10 Calc, UWP app) with the host back brush (transparent "acrylic" brush) so it overlaps, it can actually seriously mess up that app window visually (since you're doing this in an infinite loop, it's pretty bad). It's funny to mess up with Windows, but you won't be able to use this for serious programming.

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't work.

Of course not. Window contents belong to whoever provides the window procedure associated with that window. You can't just hijack someone else's window surface and hope that everything will be ok.

> How can I realize this?

You can't, given your restriction *"without using a window"*. Either you use your own window. Or reverse engineer your target application, and somehow inject your code into it.

Comment: @ted It only works, if *"it does work"* to you means *"I can occasionally see my desired output, if just for a while, and my computer doesn't instantly catch fire"*. There really are too many developers out there that don't make a difference between *"This code is correct"* and *"this code has not yet failed"*. Let's not try to add to that.

Comment: Busy-writing through a device context that the system doesn't ever evaluate, because it is rendering a full-screen, exclusive DirectX or OpenGL window doesn't magically make that ignored device context have any effect. Now while it may be possible to somewhat follow the consequences of two rendering technologies competing for the screen, we don't even know any more how many competing rendering technologies comprise what looks like a single desktop.

Comment: @ted Odd. I was sure I just posted a comment where I outlined a scenario in which the code either doesn't draw a line (most probably), or that line never makes it into the framebuffer that's displayed.

Comment: @ted When you claim that *"it worked in W95 and it still does in W10"*, have you actually verified? I mean, it's not like Windows 10 renders the desktop anywhere near Windows 95 did. There was Windows Vista, that introduced the DWM, Windows 7 that moved it to hardware again, Windows 8 to introduce the composition engine, and I don't even know what Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, version x, y, or z changed. I can just say, with confidence, that the code posted doesn't work in more than just the one scenario I outlined. And I can say with confidence, that it's ill-advised.

Comment: So you didn't verify, if/how things changed, if there's a window with Aero Glass effect under the line? Or a WPF window? Or, say, one of those not-so-newfangled Windows 10 XAML apps? Or one of those totally new-fangled WinUI 3 windows? Or a Direct2D window? With or without acrylic brush? Or one of the other Project Reunion contenders?

Comment: @ted Now that you've found out, that apparently this doesn't work as you assumed it would, could you clean up your comments that suggest that it would?

Comment: We clearly see it differently but I'll clean up to leave the space for others.